# Error with HQL QuerySyntaxException: unexpected token

Tags: java, mysql, spring, hibernate

I have a query for 3 tables with HQL class. There are some one-to-many relationships.

No problem with my database or with my entity classes for each..

I have some class hibernate DAO that query, all work good except this one..

class reportserviceimpl for jasperreport,

I got error like this

> Exception in thread "AWT-EventQueue-0" org.hibernate.hql.ast.QuerySyntaxException: unexpected token: ase near line 1, column 84 [select s.product.name as productName, sum(s.quantity) as quantity, s.sales.noTable ase noTable, s.sales.member as member, s.price as price, sum(s.subtotal) as subTotal from restodeskapp.model.SalesDetail s  where s.sales.id = :id  group by s.product.name order by s.product.name]
>           at org.hibernate.hql.ast.QuerySyntaxException.convert(QuerySyntaxException.java:31)
>           at org.hibernate.hql.ast.QuerySyntaxException.convert(QuerySyntaxException.java:24)
>           at org.hibernate.hql.ast.ErrorCounter.throwQueryException(ErrorCounter.java:59)
>           at org.hibernate.hql.ast.QueryTranslatorImpl.parse(QueryTranslatorImpl.java:258)
>           at org.hibernate.hql.ast.QueryTranslatorImpl.doCompile(QueryTranslatorImpl.java:157)
>           at org.hibernate.hql.ast.QueryTranslatorImpl.compile(QueryTranslatorImpl.java:111)
>           at org.hibernate.engine.query.HQLQueryPlan.(HQLQueryPlan.java:77)
>           at org.hibernate.engine.query.HQLQueryPlan.(HQLQueryPlan.java:56)

here my code for HBL

```
List<SalesReport> salesReports =
        sessionFactory.getCurrentSession()
        .createQuery("select s.product.name as productName,"
        + " sum(s.quantity) as quantity,"
        + " s.sales.noTable as noTable,"
        + " s.sales.member as member,"
        + " s.price as price,"
        + " sum(s.subtotal) as subTotal from SalesDetail s "
        + " where s.sales.id = :id "
        + " group by s.product.name order by s.product.name")
        .setParameter("id", id)
        .setResultTransformer(
        Transformers.aliasToBean(SalesReport.class))
        .list();
```

here my SalesReport

```
public class SalesReport {
    private String productName;
    private String member;
    private int noTable;
    private Long quantity;
    private BigDecimal subTotal;
    private BigDecimal price;
//setter getter
}
```

here my Sales

```
public class Sales implements Serializable{

    @Id @GeneratedValue
    @Column(name="ID")
    private Long id;

    @Column(name="NO_TABLE", nullable=false)
    private int noTable;

    @Temporal(TemporalType.TIMESTAMP)
    @Column(name="SALES_DATE",nullable=false)
    private Date salesDate;

    @OneToMany(mappedBy="sales",cascade=CascadeType.ALL)
    @Cascade(org.hibernate.annotations.CascadeType.DELETE_ORPHAN)
    private List<SalesDetail> salesDetails;

    @Column(name="TOTAL_SALES",precision=18,scale=0,nullable=false)
    private BigDecimal totalSales;

    @ManyToOne
    @JoinColumn(name="Member_ID")
    private Member member;
//setter getter
}
```

here my salesdetail

```
public class SalesDetail implements Serializable{

    @Id @GeneratedValue
    @Column(name="ID")
    private Long id;

    @ManyToOne
    @JoinColumn(name="PRODUCT_ID",nullable=false)
    private Product product;

    @Column(name="QUANTITY",nullable=false)
    private Integer quantity;

    @Column(name="PRICE",nullable=false,precision=18,scale=0)
    private BigDecimal price;

    @Column(name="SUBTOTAL",nullable=false,precision=18,scale=0)
    private BigDecimal subtotal = BigDecimal.ZERO;

    @ManyToOne
    @JoinColumn(name="SALES_ID",nullable=false)
    private Sales sales;
}
```

here my product

```
public class Product implements Serializable {

    @Id @GeneratedValue(strategy=GenerationType.AUTO)
    @Column(name="ID")
    private Long id;
    @Column(name="NAME",unique=true,length=200)
    private String name;
    @Column(name="DESCRIPTION",unique=false,length=500)
    private String description;
    @Column(name="PRICE",unique=false,length=200)
    private BigDecimal harga;
    @Column(name="note",unique=false,length=500)
    private String note;
    @Enumerated(EnumType.STRING)
    @Column(name="STATUS",length=20)
    private EnumStatus status;
    @Enumerated(EnumType.STRING)
    @Column(name="TYPE",length=20)
    private EnumJenisMakanan type;
    @Lob
    @Column(name="PICTURE")
    private byte[] picture;

}
```

I realy dont know whares the wrong..
please help..

thanks you..
Best regard :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your exception says `unexpected token: ase near line 1, column 84` and the error further shows you have used it here -> `s.sales.noTable ase noTable`

So, looking for `ase`, your HBL code doesn't have this error.  I would say, do a search on your code base and try to find out where else do you have this typo specified `s.sales.noTable ase noTable`.  You fix `s.sales.noTable ase noTable` -> `s.sales.noTable as noTable` the error should go away.

There are chances that you fixed it but still facing the same error.  In that condition, try to clean up your cache, delete work & temp folders and repeat a build and deploy.

See if the problem goes away.

Answer (score 2):

```
    + " s.sales.noTable ase noTable,"
```

There is a typo in the code `ase` shouldn't it be `as` ?